# Condition on resultset of a select that return null or not null values-Java

Tags: java, sql, select, null

For an application,I am checking if a table is filled so that I can retrieve that from it; otherwise I will retrive from another table. For that, I use a select and checks if it has null values by wasnull(). If it does, I execute a query; otherwise, I execute a differet query. The problem that I have is when it is null, it does not execute the query but returns null values !
Can you please show me what I am doing wrong or a better solution ?

Here is my code:

```
String reqEx = "SELECT PYE_DATEDEBUT,PYE_DATEFIN FROM PGEXCEPTPRESENCE WHERE PYE_SALARIE='"+chaine+"' ";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(reqEx);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
            req = " select jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE2,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE2"
            + " from profilpressalarie propressal join profilpresence propres on propressal.ppz_profilpres = propres.ppq_profilpres "
            + "join modelecycle modcyc on propres.PPQ_CYCLEAFFECT = modcyc.PMO_MODELECYCLE join JOURNEETYPE jour " +
            " on modcyc.PMO_JOURNEETYPE= jour.PJO_JOURNEETYPE where modcyc.PMO_ORDREJOUR='"+orderJ+"' " +
            " and propressal.PPZ_salarie= '"+chaine+"'";
    }
    else{
        while(rs.next()){
            req = " select jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE2,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE2"
                  + " from PGEXCEPTPRESENCE exc join profilpresence propres on exc.PYE_CYCLEAFFECT = propres.ppq_profilpres join modelecycle modcyc " +
                    "on propres.PPQ_CYCLEAFFECT = modcyc.PMO_MODELECYCLE join JOURNEETYPE jour " +
                    "on modcyc.PMO_JOURNEETYPE= jour.PJO_JOURNEETYPE where modcyc.PMO_ORDREJOUR='"+orderJ+"' " +
                    "and exc.PYE_SALARIE= '"+chaine+"' ";
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rs.wasNull() is meant to be used for verifying the last read column is NULL or not. If your table's first column is a primitive data type like int it will not return NULL. So in this case you need to verify if the query returns any row or not. For this please use the following if condition:

```
if (!rs.next()) {
            req = " select jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE1,jour.PJO_HORDEBPLAGE2,jour.PJO_HORFINPLAGE2"
            + " from profilpressalarie propressal join profilpresence propres on propressal.ppz_profilpres = propres.ppq_profilpres "
            + "join modelecycle modcyc on propres.PPQ_CYCLEAFFECT = modcyc.PMO_MODELECYCLE join JOURNEETYPE jour " +
            " on modcyc.PMO_JOURNEETYPE= jour.PJO_JOURNEETYPE where modcyc.PMO_ORDREJOUR='"+orderJ+"' " +
            " and propressal.PPZ_salarie= '"+chaine+"'";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.. I actually tried it before and didnt know why it doesnt work..Now, it works Thank you again :)

Comment: Please accept my answer (to increase my reputation) if it has resolved your issue :)